# div not wrapping

Tags: html, css

Is a more efficient way of doing this... for some reason I feel like this is an old way of doing this.

I have this page [HERE](http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/TrailGuide_website/) `(I'm re-creating a lynda.com webpage for a lesson)` and the wrapper doesn't actually wrap around the section `id="trailInfo"`.

In order to do that I would add br `class="br_clear"` /

Is there a more correct way of doing this? If I add `clear=both` to the section is doesn't work, I have to add it to the `br`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update your CSS with the `overflow:hidden` property inside your parent div

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}
```

**`Explanation About Clearing floats`**

A common problem with **float-based** layouts is that the **parent div's** doesn't want to stretch up to accommodate the **child floated div's**. If you will add a border around the **parent div** you'll have to command the browsers somehow to stretch up the **parent div** all the way.

Now see the problem as you were facing: [**demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/oS5bm0bE)

its because you didn't clear the floats on that time.

So the **Old Solution** of this problem is `clear:both;`

if you will add extra div after the **child floated** elements like mentioned below code this will clear the floats:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-child"></div>
  <div class="right-child"></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**New Solution** is `overflow:hidden;`
if you will give `overflow:hidden` to your `parent div` this will automatically clear all the **child floated elements** inside the **parent div**.

see the **new solution demo**: **[tinkerbin.com/WKqFS7Lc](http://tinkerbin.com/WKqFS7Lc)**

Comment: Yes that worked thanks! Can you point me in the direction to read about why that worked? I'm trying to learn all this stuff thanks!!

Comment: Hey @Kim please check the updated answer Explanation About Clearing floats i hope you will understand the things and will get the idea about the exact issue .......

Answer (score 0):

Hi now give to `#wrapper overflow:hidden;`

as like this

```
#wrapper{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgKcD.png)***

Comment: Thank You also! This did work! Now I'm trying to learn why this worked, any links to more info on this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: auto;` to wrapper class. it works

Answer (score 0):

you should use overflow:hidden; property on your wrapper.

```
#wrapper{
overflow:hidden;
height:auto;
}
```